# Can I hide the text box value if the value is 0?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, database

Please help I am able to do all the calculations I need as long as I make certain text boxes default value 0 but I do not want these boxes to show a 0 if nothing is put in them. Can I hide the text box if the value is 0? there are servral text boxs in the sheet.

**Edit:**

Op wants also to validate form ,no `submit()` if values are not numbers or are empty.

Comment: yes, you can "hide" these text boxes if their value is zero.

Comment: What are you using to hide? CSS? PHP? Show us what you have tried so far

Comment: i want the text box to appeare but only the value in the text box should be blank to fill these value come from the database where the default value is set to zero for calaculations i am using css and also php but the try has not fetched the result i tried in the calculation part

Comment: Code or it didn't happen.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/n2uRU/)

```
$(function() {
  $('input[type="text"]').each(function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    if(value == 0) {    
      $(this).val('');
    }
  });

});
```

Comment: this code will hide the text box i want the text box to appere but the default value to be hidden

Answer (score 0):

Answer to your comment about validation of form if input's value is not number or is empty :[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/bZB2W/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {

     $('input[type="submit"]').click(function(e){
             var isEmpty=false;
             e.preventDefault();

            $('input[type="text"]').each(function() {
                if($(this).val() ==0||$(this).val() =='' || isNaN($(this).val()))   {
                  $(this).val('');
                  isEmpty=true;
                }


            });

         if(isEmpty)  {
             alert('please fill all values');
             return false;
         }
         else $('form').submit();

   });

});
```

---

First Answer :This solves your issue : [**JSFIDDLE DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/qza4t/)

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('input[type="text"]').each(function()
    {
        if($(this).val() == 0) $(this).val('');
    });
});
```

Comment: this will solve half of my problem the rest half is if the user leaves some blank text box to fill later in an update at that time the the database would be filled with blank cell which will make the equation not work for the remaining part pls help me in this also

Comment: No offense but you should at least TRY to do it yourself first.

Comment: i tried the onsubmit function the reverse of the values but this not happend and the database got updated with null values $(document).onsubmit(function(){
    $('input[type="text"]').each(function() {
        if($(this).val() =='')  $(this).val('0');
    });

Comment: @user2774977 check my new answer and test de demo